# How to show time elapsed in a media element

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, uwp-xaml, mediaelement

I want to show elapsed time of a video in a textbox while it is playing. Means, Textbox value should change in each second. How can I achieve it?

```
<MediaElement Name="videoMediaElement" MediaOpened="videoMediaElement_MediaOpened" Width="450" Height="250" MediaEnded="Element_MediaEnded"  />

TimeSpan  _duration = videoMediaElement.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan;
tb_display_elapsedtime.Text = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", _duration.Minutes, _duration.Seconds);
```

Where should I written this code for dynamically getting the elapsed time while playing video? Is there any event for it?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the [Position](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_MediaElement_Position) as a TimeStamp from the videoMediaElement MediaElement.

Comment: No there isn't any event. You can setup a timer: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a9c25c27-079a-474c-beec-4dd69052a79e/how-to-bind-slider-position-to-current-elementmedia-time-value-?forum=wpf

Comment: can you refer any link for ot?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a9c25c27-079a-474c-beec-4dd69052a79e/how-to-bind-slider-position-to-current-elementmedia-time-value-?forum=wpf